# Picking up the smallest item(string) from a list

Tags: python, list

```
mylist = ['breast:entire breast quadrant ', 'breast:entire breast ', 'breast:entire breast and endocrine system ', 'breast:entire breast quadrant ', 'breast:entire breast ', 'breast:entire breast and endocrine system ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen and pelvis ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen and pelvis ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ']
```

In the above list, I have two keywords (breast and chest) and the related values. I need to pick up the **smallest value** ( **by number of words**) for **each key word**.

I would prefer to pick up 1) `'breast:entire breast '`  2) `'chest:entire chest wall '`

Could you please help? To be executed in Python.

Comment: Can you please clarify which programming language this is? Can you also show us what you already tried, instead of only the array?

Comment: To be done in Python. I tried to split the sentences and count the words.

Comment: In that case, consider adding the tag `python` to your question, that way it will be visible for users that 'watch' this tag ;)

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: After splitting the sentence, counted words. But not not able to get the lowest number.

Comment: Thanks Bear Brown. The sorting suggestion worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by use sorted list and dict.
first you can craete the list of lists:

```
[x.split(':') for x in mylist]
```

the result is :

```
[['breast', 'entire breast quadrant '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast and endocrine system '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast quadrant '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast and endocrine system '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen and pelvis '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen and pelvis '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery ']
```

now we can order it by first value and length of the words in the second value

```
sorted(
     [x.split(':') for x in mylist],
     key=lambda x: (x[0],len(x[1].split())),
     reverse=True
)
```

we use the reverse to put min value to the end of the sorted list, and the result is:

```
[['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen and pelvis '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen and pelvis '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest and abdomen '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall artery '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['chest', 'entire chest wall '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast and endocrine system '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast and endocrine system '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast quadrant '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast quadrant '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast '],
 ['breast', 'entire breast ']]
```

and now make a dict from the sorted list, the dict has unique keys so while processing the result will take last values for each first value:

```
dict(sorted( 
    [x.split(':') for x in mylist], 
    key=lambda x: (x[0],len(x[1])), 
    reverse=True 
    ))
```

result is

```
{'chest': 'entire chest wall ', 'breast': 'entire breast '}
```

Comment: glad to help you, don't forget to accept the answer,it needs for others who will search the same issue.

Comment: I accepted. Since I am new here, I guess the system recorded but not displaying.

Comment: i think you click up-vote, but need to click accepted located under the down-vote

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['breast:entire breast quadrant ', 'breast:entire breast ', 'breast:entire breast and endocrine system ', 'breast:entire breast quadrant ', 'breast:entire breast ', 'breast:entire breast and endocrine system ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen and pelvis ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen and pelvis ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ', 'chest:entire chest and abdomen ', 'chest:entire chest wall ', 'chest:entire chest wall artery ']

string1 = 'breast:'
string2 = 'chest:'
c1 = float("inf")
c2 = float("inf")
for x in mylist:
    if 'breast' in x :
        c_idx = x.index(':')
        x = x [ c_idx+1 : ]
        cnt = x.count(" ")
        if cnt < c1 :
            string_b = x
            c1 = cnt
        else :
            continue
    elif 'chest' in x :
        c_idx = x.index(':')
        x = x [ c_idx+1 : ]
        cnt = x.count(" ")
        if cnt < c2 :
            string_c = x
            c2 = cnt
        else :
            continue
print(string1+string_b)
print(string2+string_c)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Other option

```
sublisted = [ x.split(":") for x in set(mylist)]

breast = min([ item[1] for item in sublisted if item[0] == "breast" ], key=len)
chest = min([ item[1] for item in sublisted if item[0] == "chest" ], key=len)

print(breast) #=> entire breast 
print(chest) #=> entire chest wall
```

---

You can customize or build a method to get the string format you desire, for example:

```
sublisted = [ x.split(":") for x in set(mylist) ]

def find_min(lst, str):
  found = min([ item[1] for item in sublisted if item[0] == str ], key=len)
  return str + ': ' + found

keys = { x[0] for x in sublisted }
for k in keys:
  print(find_min(sublisted, k))
# chest: entire chest wall 
# breast: entire breast
```